# Is running gzip compression on a directory tree already in the process of being gzip'd safe?

Tags: compression, tar, gzip

Can I simultaneously compress the same directory tree using `tar -zcvf` (gzip) (e.g. in two separate shells, one after the other but the second one running before the first one finished) with two different processes (shell instances), such that the two resulting `.tar.gz` archives are created just as if only one shell had run `tar -zcvf` after the other?

I.e. such that each final `archive.tar.gz` is not somehow damaged as a result of the simultaneity of two running `tar -zcvf` on the same directory tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tar cz` does not 'compress [the] directory tree', or the files; it creates an archive file (tar) that contains a *copy* of the files in the tree and compresses that *archive*.

**Yes multiple `tar c`** with or without compression (any of `z j J`) concurrently reading from the same (or partly the same) files **will produce correct results**, although it may take longer due to contention; in some cases it may even take longer than doing them consecutively.

It doesn't matter whether they run under the same shell or different shells. If they run under different *userids* and any userid doesn't have access to all desired directories and files then that one will produce an incomplete result, but that same fault occurs whether anything else is running or not.